# What does each part of this axis environment do?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

```
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}%
    [grid=both,
     minor tick num=5,
     grid style={line width=.1pt, draw=gray!10},
     major grid style={line width=.2pt,draw=gray!50},
     axis lines=middle,
     enlargelimits={abs=0.2}
    ]
    \addplot[domain=-1:1,samples=100,smooth,red] {sin(deg(pi*x))};
    \addplot coordinates {
        (0,0)
        (1,1)
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Why don't you compile it and see what the output is? What happens if you change various values? What if you change the colours? What if you change the function, say `sin`->`cos`? What happens if you remove the options (between the square brackets `[` and `]`)?

Comment: Have you looked at the `pgfplots` manual? There will be some explanation of all of it there.